# Qclipboard how to get the destination path

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently developing an app which as a kind of file browser. I'm trying to move some files from my app to any other location using drag and drop.

I do not find how the clipboard is able to determine the copy. Currently, when moving a file from my app to the finder, a text clipping file is created to the destination path I have selected. I need to catch this information. I'm expecting to find it in the clipboard as it seems that clipboard is able to create a file at the right location.

I have tried to use the QClipboard class as the clipboard create a txt file in the selected detination path. As I have a file to transfer, I need to catch the destination path

Any idea on how to retrieve the destination path ?  CLipboard class seems more easy as the clipboard is able to copy/create a file at the rigth location. Any idea on how to do it ?

I have created:

```
QWidget *pWin = QApplication::activeWindow();

QClipboard *clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
```

But no way to find methods to extract the latest highlighted finder folder for example but clipboard is supposed to be aware of.

Seb

Comment: I dont think QClipboard is creating the file, but e.g. the OS. QClipboard only contains the mime-data and mime-type you've added, all the actions done at the drop are handled by the "object" the data is dropped at.